# UnsupportedOperationException android internal storage from JUNIT

Tags: android, junit, storage

I am trying to create a file from Android Junit in the internal storage using the MockContext and it throws UnsupportedOperationException.

```
MockContext mockContext = new MockContext();
FileOutputStream fos = mockContext.openFileOutput(LOG_FILE_NAME,
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Is there a standard way for testing file operations using Android JUNITs?

Comment: Check out the [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/mock/MockContext.html): _All methods are non-functional and throw UnsupportedOperationException._ You have to extend it and write your only implementation if you want to use it.

Comment: @yorkw please post your comment as the answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/mock/MockContext.html):

> A mock Context class. All methods are non-functional and throw UnsupportedOperationException. You can use this to inject other dependencies, mocks, or monitors into the classes you are testing.

You have to extend MockContext and write the corresponding method implementation if you want to use that method.